# A question about "UNION ALL" statement, MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Recently, I wrote a SQL query like followings:

```
SELECT DESCR, ip, CPUCpuUtil_day, CPUWio_day
FROM (SELECT res.res_descr DESCR,
node.ip ip,
(ifnull(ROUND(max(CASE WHEN kpi_no = 100000041 THEN k.valuemax END), 2), 0)) CPUCpuUtil_day,
(ifnull(ROUND(max(CASE WHEN kpi_no = 100000041 THEN k.valuemax END), 2), 0)) CPUWio_day
      FROM res_object res
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT res.res_id, p.kbp, p.valuemax, p.time_id, p.kpi_no
      FROM res_object res
      LEFT JOIN pm_day_p_reshost p ON p.kbp = res.res_id
      AND (p.kpi_no = 100000041 OR p.kpi_no = 100000041) WHERE res.classname = 'ResHost'
      AND p.time_id >= '20180913'
      AND p.time_id < '20180914') k ON k.res_id = res.res_id, res_node node, res_multiselect rs, res_dim_os os
      WHERE rs.multiselect_id = res.multiselect_id
      AND node.res_id = res.res_id
      AND os.os_id = node.os_id
      AND OS.DESCR = 'Linux'
      GROUP BY res.res_descr, node.ip) x
```

This query will take more than one minutes to show me the datas, because of massive data. But if I add the UNION ALL statement: `UNION ALL SELECT 1 res_id, 1 valuemax, 1 kbp, 1 time_id, 1 kpi_no` or a UNION ALL statement which will get 0 rows after `AND p.time_id >= '20180913' AND p.time_id < '20180914'`, this query will be completed in three seconds. 
So why could this be? Why is it so quick after adding a such a UNION ALL statement? 
I wonder the principle of it. 
Any answer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how you are adding union all in this query. Show that sample as well.

Comment: @IShubh After the` statement AND p.time_id >= '20180913' AND p.time_id < '20180914'`.

Comment: Examine the [query plans](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) and play spot the difference

Comment: @CharlesA.Guo Please, when someone asks to post a query, just post the query. Don't describe it. Post it. Your description doesn't make any sense. What you describe is not a valid statement.

Comment: You claim that your query is slow because of massive data. But I suspect that your query is slow because it's a poorly written query. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a suggestion  (but to complex for a comment)

looking to your original query seems you have some strange coding

what mean   the column separated  by comma in 
k ON k.res_id = res.res_id, res_node node, res_multiselect rs, res_dim_os os

assuming you are mixing explict  join and implict join sintax basec on where condition. You should use only the explict join sintax  and not the older implict sintax

and you have WHERE condition for left joined  table column in  inner left join, if you use where for left joined  tables these work as  INNER JOIN  ..
(And you are select two time the same  values with different column alias CPUCpuUtil_day and CPUWio_day)
you query could be refactored  as

```
    SELECT DESCR
        , ip
        , CPUCpuUtil_day
        , CPUWio_day
    FROM (
        SELECT res.res_descr DESCR
            , node.ip ip
            , (ifnull(ROUND(max(CASE WHEN kpi_no = 100000041 
                            THEN k.valuemax END), 2), 0)) CPUCpuUtil_day
            , (ifnull(ROUND(max(CASE WHEN kpi_no = 100000041 
                            THEN k.valuemax END), 2), 0)) CPUWio_day
         FROM res_object res
         LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT res.res_id
                , p.kbp
                , p.valuemax
                , p.time_id
                , p.kpi_no
            FROM res_object res
            INNER JOIN pm_day_p_reshost p ON p.kbp = res.res_id
                AND (p.kpi_no = 100000041 OR p.kpi_no = 100000041) 
                    AND res.classname = 'ResHost'
                        AND p.time_id >= '20180913'
                            AND p.time_id < '20180914'
            ) k ON k.res_id = res.res_id 
         INNER JOIN res_multiselect rs ON rs.multiselect_id = res.multiselect_id
         INNER JOIN res_node node ON  node.res_id = res.res_id
         INNER JOIN res_dim_os os ON os.os_id = node.os_id
            AND OS.DESCR = 'Linux'
        GROUP BY res.res_descr, node.ip 
    ) x
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.